# create-next-app failed to replace env in config

Tags: next.js

I am trying to create a new nextjs project using

`npx create-next-app --ts`

However I am getting this error `An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}".`

When the project tries to build. I am confused about this as this is a blank project from scratch - there are no .npmrc file in the root and inside my .bash_profile I have this defined.

Anybody know why I am getting this error?

Comment: What version of Node are you running? NextJS requires Node.js 14.6.0 or newer

Answer (score 0):

With `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` error it seems like you're running `npm publish` to [publish a package](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages). You'll see multiple `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` in the docs if you search for it on the site.

To run the build process, make sure you use the command `npm run build` or `npx next build` in your **project directory**. After you download the project, you'll have to `cd yourProjectName` in the terminal and then run the build command.

Additionally, you need to make sure that your running at least `Node.js version 14.6.0`. You can check this by running the command `node -v` in your terminal or command prompt.

As a side note: I went through the whole process on my machine today to verify and built it successfully. I'm using `Node.js version v16.18.0`.